# Incorrect results when combining full-text search and regular comparison

Tags: sql-server-2019

```
create table "Foo"
(
"id" integer identity (1000, 1) not null,
"name" nvarchar(100) not null
)
alter table "Foo" add constraint "Foo_PK" primary key ("id");
create fulltext index on "Foo" ("name" language 0x0) key index "Foo_PK" on "catalog" with stoplist = off;
```

The following query returns no rows

```
select * from "Foo" where contains("name", ' "پ*" ') and "id" > 1082;
```

While there are 26 rows matched by `contains("name", ' "پ*" ')` and 87 matched by `"id" > 1082` individually. The following two queries have 23 rows in common, oddly, their intersection returns no rows.

```
select * from "Foo" where contains("name", ' "پ*" ');
select * from "Foo" where "id" > 1082;
```

And more strangely, the following query returns exactly 23 rows. All "id"s are above 1082.

```
select * from "Foo" where contains("name", ' "پ*" ') and "id" > 1081;
```

Someone please explain what is going on in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think your primary problem is that you are using non-Unicode string delimiters for Unicode data.

Compare:

```
SELECT  ' "پ*" ';
SELECT N' "پ*" ';
-------^ this N is important
```

Comment: N' "پ*" ' did not fix it

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it simply by dropping and creating the index again.
Still don't know why it happened and how to prevent it from happening in the future.